# Pine script ? understanding

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Could someone confirm I am reading this correctly as I am quite new to pinescript

```
vcolor= Oo > Cc ? color.red : up > down? color.green:color.red
```

Is this essentially an if statement to determine color?

So my understanding would be

```
if its Oo > Cc 
    vcolor = red
else if up > down 
    vcolor = green
```

What does the last color.red mean and why would you use this over an if statement if that's what it means?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`?:` is called [Ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

You can write that statement as:

```
vcolor = if (Oo > Cc)
    color.red
else if (up > down)
    color.green
else
    color.red
```

So, the last `color.red` is if none of those statements are `true`.

As to why you may want to use this is just personal preference. I personnaly like it because it allows me to write those statements in one line.

Comment: But never, ever write nested ternary operators. They are very unreadable after 6 months :-)